# Are these commands materially, or only semantically different?

Tags: shell-script, curl

In a shell script that's using `curl` to fetch a script, then executing it, are these two approaches materially different?

```
curl http://address-to-some-script/dosomething.sh | sudo tee /usr/bin/dosomething.sh
```

...vs...

```
sudo curl http://address-to-some-script/dosomething.sh >> /usr/bin/dosomething.sh
```

There's something about the `sudo` right before `curl` in the second command that's giving me pause, but I can't articulate whether or how it's different (riskier?) than the first.

Comment: There is never a reason to run `curl` with `sudo`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of material differences.

```
curl http://address-to-some-script/dosomething.sh | sudo tee /usr/bin/dosomething.sh
```

runs `curl` as the current user, and `tee` as root; it also clears the contents of `/usr/bin/dosomething.sh` before writing to it.

```
sudo curl http://address-to-some-script/dosomething.sh >> /usr/bin/dosomething.sh
```

runs `curl` as root, and tries to append to `/usr/bin/dosomething.sh` with the permissions of the current user (the current shell sets the redirection up).